# How to show Save success message use compact() and ->with() in Laravel 7.3.5?

Tags: laravel

I have a piece of code and I'm trying to find out why this code not working!

```
 return view('backend.accommodation.application.application_list_mp',compact('acc_app')) ->with('success', 'Data Saved successfully');

                        
 return view('backend.accommodation.application.application_list_mp',compact('acc_app'),['success'=>'Data Saved successfully']);
```

What is my wrong here?

Comment: By not working, what exactly do you mean? What do you have in your blade file to display session messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In return view I prefer

```
return view('backend.accommodation.application.application_list_mp',compact('acc_app')) ->with('success', 'Data Saved successfully');
```

And in view like below

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible show">
        {{ session('success') }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Put something like this in the view file:

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible show">
        {{ session('success') }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
@endif
```